# Get Index of class within Click Function

Tags: jquery

I want to append the index to `.modalwindows .modAcContent` that way I can show/hide the content. This is what I'm hoping to include +index

```
$(".modalwindows .modAcContent"+index).css('display','none');
```

So, when I click .modAcTitle it changes to BLOCK:

```
<div class="modAcContent acc_content0" style="display: block;">Content Goes here</div>
```

When I click it again it changes to NONE

```
<div class="modAcContent acc_content0" style="display: none;">Content Goes here</div>
```

I thought I could use this, but it doesn't get the index properly within the click function.

```
var index = $(".modalwindows .modAcContent").index()
```

Here is my click function and demo: https://jsfiddle.net/akagg4j1/6/

```
    $('.modAcTitle:not(.modAcLink)').click(function() {

var index = $(".modalwindows .modAcContent").index()

        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') != true) {
          $(this).removeClass('modAcActive');
          $(this).next().slideUp('normal')
          $(".modalwindows .modAcContent"+index).css('display','none'); 

        } else {

          $(this).siblings('.modAcTitle').removeClass('modAcActive'); 
          $(this).siblings('.modAcContent').slideUp('normal')
          if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
            $(this).addClass('modAcActive');
            $(".modalwindows .modAcContent"+index).css('display','block');
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');

          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You want to change the class name of your elements by appending an number when you click?  That does not seem very useful. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I cleaned up my request. Just want to show/hide content, but I need to get the index of the class so I can show/hide it.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. you have in your question a class `acc_content0`, so with a number (index?) attached to the class name. First I don't understand why you need that. It is not really the practice to number classes so each element gets a different class. That kills the whole I idea of a class. Secondly, I don't see such numbered classes in your fiddle, which seems able to show/hide parts. So I really don't get what you are after. Your update doesn't clarify it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I have a feeling it wasn't intuitive to see each time my accordion is clicked in my demo, you'll notice it show/hides content at the very bottom. The goal is to show/hide modAcContent0 or modAcContent1 or modAcContent2. Sure, I can change the classes to IDs -- no problem, but in order to talk to those BOTTOM divs, I need to get the unique class (in your case the ID as you instructed). Let me modify the code so its an ID instead of a class. Just a second.

Comment: But what's wrong with `next()`? That seems to do the thing, no? I don't see why you need numbered `id` values for that...

Comment: OK - This is NOT coded correctly to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve, however the HIDDEN divs are now assigned ID of acc_content0, 1, 2, 3, etc (instead of unique classes as you point out) but when you click on the titles to show/hide the hidden DIVs however it should be coded to show/hide display those IDs account0,1,2,3 https://jsfiddle.net/akagg4j1/8/

Comment: Just like your previous fiddle it seems to work. Still wonder why you cannot achieve this with `next`, but more importantly: I still don't get what your question is: your code seems to work.

Comment: I solved the issue I was having and I completed my accordion. https://jsfiddle.net/akagg4j1/9/

Answer (score -1):

The trick was to utilize this click function

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/7201/

```
$('.showSingle').click(function(){
              $('.targetDiv').hide();
              $('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
        });
```

Here's a demo of my finished product. It works for both desktop and mobile. This is great for CMS use cases, which is what it was designed to be used.

https://jsfiddle.net/akagg4j1/12/